# SecureRandom stream weird behavior with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, thread-safety, secure-random

I'm trying to generate random values using [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html), specifically its support of streams. Ideally the values should be generated on a constant basis, so the stream could be infinite:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
Iterator<Integer> idIterator = secureRandom.ints().distinct().iterator();
```

The documentation states that *"`SecureRandom` objects are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads."* However when multiple threads retrieve the next value from the iterator, I get an error in (at least) one of the threads that appears to be due to a race condition:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> idIterator.next());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> idIterator.next());
t1.start();
t2.start();


Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceSpliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:409)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.lambda$spliterator$0(AbstractPipeline.java:367)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.init(StreamSpliterators.java:142)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:157)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$IntWrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:358)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$2Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:726)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$2Adapter.nextInt(Spliterators.java:732)
    at java.base/java.util.PrimitiveIterator$OfInt.next(PrimitiveIterator.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.PrimitiveIterator$OfInt.next(PrimitiveIterator.java:86)
    at example.Example.foo(Example.java:39)
```

When I run the code several times, I sometimes get another kind of exception (NullPointerException).

The behavior is the same if I limit the stream and remove the `distinct()` operation:

```
secureRandom.ints().limit(100).iterator();
```

**EDIT:**

On the other hand, if I avoid using a stream and just call `SecureRandom.nextInt()` from each thread, **no race condition is observed as expected.**

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> secureRandom.nextInt());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> secureRandom.nextInt());
t1.start();
t2.start(); // code is thread-safe
```

I'm wondering why the iterator changes behavior? Especially that the Javadocs of the `ints()` method states that *"a pseudorandom int value is generated as if it's the result of calling the method `nextInt()`"*.

***P.S.:** Of course I can solve this but synchronizing the threads acquiring the next value.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `SecureRandom` itself is thread-safe, streams are not. The entire Streams API was built to be accessed by a single thread. While intermediate operations may be executed in parallel, they must be called from a single thread.

Therefore neither `ints()` nor its iterator are thread-safe.

So what you can do, is create one stream per thread.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> secureRandom.ints().distinct().iterator().next());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> secureRandom.ints().distinct().iterator().next());
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would be interesting to know more about how thread-safety works with streams, specifically with `iterator()`. The proposed solution, however, is not very suitable, as the intention is to ensure distinct values (i.e. no values are repeatedly generated even if this is highly unlikely).

Comment: @MAnouti I explained thread-safety of streams. What else would you like to know? To ensure distinct values across multiple threads you will need to implement your solution (maybe use a concurrent hash set).

Comment: Here I'm interested specifically in the `iterator()` operation which seems special in that it does not evaluate the entire stream, unlike other terminal operations. The docs of the `ints()` method state "a pseudorandom int value is as if it's the result of calling the method `nextInt()`." Now if I simply use `nextInt()`, no race condition occurs. So just wondering why `iterator()` would behave differently (I've updated the question to clarify).

Comment: I can accept the answer if there is a reference to the fact that streams are just not thread-safe in general (like an official docs or discussion). Though it would still feel like it's breaking the thread-safety guarantee of `SecureRandom`.

Comment: @MAnouti I think thread-safe classes can have spun-off classes that are not thread-safe. The contract of `Iterator` does not mandate that it be thread-safe. The stream's iterator would behave differently because it is generated from a stream, and streams are not thread-safe.